# Hp pavilion dv4 1211 power adapter does not work

Tags: laptop, power-supply, hp-pavilion

i have laptop `Hp pavilion dv4 1211`

i have a problem with may power adapter (Hp pavilion dv4 1211) .
when i attach with laptop(Turn off) the indicator light will rise up . but real problem is start when i Turn On laptop the indicator light going to on/off rapidly and charge in not connected with laptop.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the comments of your [duplicate question](https://superuser.com/q/583447/97028), there are two things which could be causing problems. These are common issues because people often put their laptop in a carrying bag with the AC adapter connected and it puts excessive side pressure on the connector or wire.

1. The AC adapter has a broken wire or connector. Sometime this is obvious by the condition of the wire or actual broken insulation around the connector.
2. The connector on the laptop is damaged (where the AC adapter plugs in). This is usually indicated by a very loose connection where the AC adapter connects to the laptop.

You may want to have a professional look at it to ensure you know which item needs to be replaced.